# Run Python codes on subdirectories

Tags: python

How do I run python codes (.py) on subdirectories from the main folder?

What is the easiest way to do this?

I tried:

```
os.chdir("path") #path = path to subdirectory 
import abc #abc = module on subdirectory
```

Error:

```
ImportError: No module named abc
```

Comment: You want to import `abc` even though it resides in a different path? Which version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using python 2.7. Actually I have multiple python files, abc1, abc2, abc3, all of them are on subdirectories

Comment: Are they in a single subdirectory? You could consider turning the directory into a package. That'll make things easier for you.

Comment: No, they are different subdirectories. I just want a simple solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to import `abc` into your current module, even though they're located on different folders. Depending on your python, there are different ways to do this:

Python2.x

```
import imp
abc = imp.load_source('abc', '/path/to/abc.py')
```

Python 3.4

```
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader
abc = SourceFileLoader('abc', '/path/to/abc.py').load_module()
```

In either case, `abc` will be imported for use as usual.

```
>>> abc
<module 'abc' from '/path/to/abc.py'>
```

This is cleaner because it does not involve polluting your `sys.path`.

Comment: I am using import imp, but python throws an error saying "Permission Denied"

Comment: Hmm, try running python with sudo?

Comment: @pnkjmndhl Just tried it and it works fine. Check your directory permissions. That's not related to this problem. Open a terminal as admin and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

```
import sys
sys.path
sys.path.append('/path/to/the/example_file.py')
import example_file
```

Comment: I need to do this on multiple files, I dont want to append multiple paths to sys.path

Answer (score 0):

well, just do it

```
import sys
sys.path
sys.path.append('/path/to/the/example_file1.py')
sys.path.append('/path/to/the/example_file2.py')
sys.path.append('/path/to/the/example_file3.py')
import example_file1
import example_file2
import example_file3
```

Comment: Yes, maybe I would do this, and remove the path when the job is done.